# Check if a proxy connects in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I'm writing a chrome extension which connects to a proxy server via the the "fixed_servers" mode in chrome.proxy. I'd like to provide a list of servers and have try to connect to all of them and stay connected to the first one that that it can reach the internet through.

I tried:

```
if(!navigator.onLine()){
    nextProxy();
}
```

but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, provide more details regarding your attempts (and results). E.g. what is `nextProxy()` ? Where is this code run from ? What does "that didn't work" imply (i.e. what happened) ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Sometimes I would be running a connection through a dead proxy server which I couldn't connect to the internet through but it would still say I was online. I assume because I could reach a server on the way to the dead proxy server. Cool that it can figure that out but not helpful. Anyway, I got it working with AJAX. Thanks for trying to help. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an AJAX request. If the request is successful I'm online. If it's not, I'm maybe online but I'll assume offline.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        timeout: 3000,
        success : function(data){
            ...
        },
        error : function(){
            ...
        }
});
```